# "control +a" not working on mac, but "control + e" works

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Today <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> combination stopped working. So I cannot move cursor to beginning of line in terminal or browser input.

Although yesterday it was working well. <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> works good.

In `eventViewer of KeyRemap4MacBook app` I cans see that when I press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> key is logged, but <kbd>a</kbd> key not logged.

[image: "control" key is logged, but "a" key not]

When I press <kbd>a</kbd> key without control it is typed in any application and logged in eventViewer.

[image: "a" key is logged without control]

Why <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> not working? How to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was application `Music Player for VK Lite`. When quit it, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> start working again.